# Doctrine search a string in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I hope you can help :)

This is how the table looks:

```
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| firstName  | lastName       | email            | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| John       | Doe            | john@doe.com     | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| John       | Michaels       | john@michaels.es | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
```

This is how the code looks:

```
if($_GET['search-customers'] != '') {
    $busqueda = $_GET['search-customers'];
    $query->andWhere("(c.firstName LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.lastName LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.email LIKE '%$busqueda%')"); 
}
```

With that QUERY:

- If I input: *John* in the search box, **it gives me the 2 results.
  OK**
- If I input: *John D* in the search box, **it doesn't give me any result. FAIL**

All right, I understand, When I type "*John D*", it try to find first in firstName (doesn't match) and also it doesn't match *lastName* or *email*.

How can I combine them?

The idea its to **find the complete string in all possibilities**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to concat firstName and lastName. I excluded the email then the query looks like that:

```
    $busqueda = $_GET['search-customers'];
    $names = explode(' ',$busqueda);
    $hasemail = strpos('@', $busqueda);

    if ( $hasemail ) {
        $query->andWhere("c.email LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
    } else {
      $query->andWhere("( CONCAT(c.firstName,' ',c.lastName) LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.email LIKE '%$busqueda%')"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I will provide you a different alternative using [MySQL's Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Lets begin to prepare the table:

```
ALTER TABLE persons ADD FULLTEXT (`firstname`, `lastname`);
```

Now, `firstname` and `lastname` are columns to be used by full-text in order to search for matches:

```
SELECT * FROM persons
WHERE MATCH (firstname,lastname)
AGAINST ('John D' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

The result will be:

```
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| firstName  | lastName       | email            | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| John       | Doe            | john@doe.com     | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
| John       | Michaels       | john@michaels.es | etc...  |
+------------+----------------+------------------+---------+
```

Why both? Because `John` (as a word) was found, however `John Doe` is in the first row because has much similitude with the term of search.

Say, that lets apply this tool with Doctrine. I will assume that your model looks like this:

```
class Person{

    /** @column(type="string", name="firstname")*/
    protected $firstName;

    /** @column(type="string", name="lastname")*/
    protected $lastName;

    /** @column(type="string")*/
    protected $email;
}
```

Lets create the search function:

```
public function search($term){
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

    // Specify the object type to be returned in results
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Models\Person', 'p');

    // references each attribute with table's columns 
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'firstName', 'firstName');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'lastName', 'lastname');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'email', 'email');

    // create a native query
    $sql = 'select p.firstName, p.lastname, p.email from persons p
            where match(p.firstname, p.lastname) against(?)';

    // execute the query
    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, $term);

    // getting the results
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Finnally, and example:

```
$term = 'John D';
$results = search($term);
// two results
echo count($results);
```

Additional notes:

1. Before mysql 5.7, Full-Text only can be added just to `MyISAM` tables.
2. Only can be indexed `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `TEXT` columns.
3. When using `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` in a search, mysql returns an empty resultse when the results represent `< 50%` of the records.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the `explode` function like this:

```
$busqueda = $_GET['search-customers'];
$names = explode(' ',$busqueda);
if(count($names)>1){
  $query->andWhere("(c.firstName LIKE '%{$names[0]}%' AND c.lastName LIKE '%{$names[1]}%')"); 
}else{
  $query->andWhere("(c.firstName LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.lastName LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.email LIKE '%$busqueda%')"); 
}
```

but, using `like %word%` is inefficient, because it can't use index.

Comment: Hi, thanks but this only will work if the first name its a simple word. For example, if the name its "Marin Luther" and the lastname is "King" it won't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you'd better offer two  search boxes for name.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository you could do something like this:

```
public function findByTerms($terms) : array
{
    $alias = "d";

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias);

    foreach (explode(" ", $terms) as $i => $term) {

        $qb
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX( // nested condition
                $qb->expr()->like($alias . ".name", ":term" . $i),
                $qb->expr()->like($alias . ".description", ":term" . $i)
            ))
            ->setParameter("term" . $i, "%" . $term . "%")
        ;
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

The Query Builder is able to generate complex queries that scale to your needs